# Error with google-sparsehash in mac os x mavericks 10.9.3

Tags: c++, macos, clang, tr1

I'm compiling a C++ project that depends on `google-sparsehash`.
So I did install sparse through `brew install google-sparsehash --cc=gcc-4.2` command.
But, when I finally compile my project I got `fatal error: 'tr1/functional' file not found`. I'd like to solve this problem, could you help me?

The output of the compiler is showed bellow:

```
c++ -- cb/allBalances.cpp
c++ -- cb/allAddresses.cpp
c++ -- callback.cpp
c++ -- cb/closure.cpp
c++ -- cb/dumpTX.cpp
c++ -- parser.cpp
c++ -- cb/pristine.cpp
c++ -- cb/rewards.cpp
clang: clang: clangclang: : clangclang: : clangclang: : warning: warning: warning: warning: warning: warning: warning: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'argument unused during compilation: '-fno-check-new'

In file included from cb/rewards.cpp:4:
In file included from ./util.h:103:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/dense_hash_map:34:
/usr/local/include/sparsehash/dense_hash_map:106:10: fatal error: 'tr1/functional' file not found
In file included from cb/pristine.cpp:4:
In file included from ./util.h:103:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/dense_hash_map:34:
/usr/local/include/sparsehash/dense_hash_map:106:10: fatal error: 'tr1/functional' file not found
In file included from cb/closure.cpp:4:
In file included from ./util.h:103:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/dense_hash_map:34:
/usr/local/include/sparsehash/dense_hash_map:106:10: fatal error: 'tr1/functional' file not found
#include HASH_FUN_H                 // for hash<>#include HASH_FUN_H                 // for hash<>
     ^
```

When I type `c++ -v` I get:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Thank you.

Comment: `gcc-4.2` is a pretty **old version**, can't you use a more up to date one?